# Can someone spot my error in the this question involving work done?

Tags: calculus, integration

A 2000 lb elevator is suspended by a 200 ft cable that weighs 10 lb/ft. How much work is done in lifting the elevator 40 feet? That cable starts out with 200 ft out.

I start with this:

- 2000 lbs (weight of the elevator)
- 200 - x  (weight of the cable per 10 ft)

So I set up my equation:

$$ \int_0^{40} 2000 + 10(200-x)$$

Which comes out to:

$$ \int_0^{40} 4000 - 10x $$

Integrate:

$$ 4000 - 5x^2 $$

When I plug in 40 I end up getting -8000 and plugging in 0 gives me 4000. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: how is the integral of $4000$ equal to $4000$?

Comment: Should be 4000x. Wow, that one hurts! Thanks Alex

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments:

$$\int 4000\;dx = 4000x\ne4000$$

$$\ddot\smile$$